# How to unzip files to folder in C#

Tags: c#, unzip

I'am trying to unzip files from .zip file in C# (Forms App)
I got something like this:

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

i have strings zip and extract Path but i have an error "CS0234".
My libraries:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly? Read the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Comment: If you already have using System.IO.Compression you don't need to add it in front of the rest. It should just be "ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);"

Comment: I got "ZipFile does not exist in current context

Comment: Then it's most likely what @dr.null suggested. Expand the references in your project and see if System.IO.Compression.FileSystem is there

Answer (score 2):

The following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files) confirms what has been suggested in the comments, when it says the following:

> The following examples show some of the operations you can perform
> with compressed files. These examples require the following NuGet
> packages to be added to your project:
>
> - System.IO.Compression
> - System.IO.Compression.ZipFile
>
> If you're using .NET Framework, add references to these two libraries to your project:
>
> - System.IO.Compression
> - System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

You need to add an assembly reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to reference System.IO.Compresssion and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in your project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Ok i got an answer!
It was just an Visual Studio error. I recopied the code and it worked!

Comment: Well done on finding a solution but you should probably not have posted it as an answer in this form. This answer doesn't detail exactly what you did to resolve the error, and "just recopying the code" is unlikely to solve a missing reference error. If it did truly solve the problem then it is likely your problem was caused by a typo or some other minor thing that is unlikely to help future people landing in this question; your question should probably just be deleted